# How do I change the gender of Siri’s voice on the HomePod?

Tags: settings, siri, homekit, homepod

[This article](https://imore.com/how-customize-hey-siri-homepod#language) implies there’s a “Language” and “Siri Voice” section in the HomePod settings of the Home app; unfortunately, these sections don’t appear for me:

[image]

How do I enable this configuration option?

Comment: What region (country) are you in?  From my recollection, it's limited to US and UK at the moment.

Comment: @Allan United States?